# Rails 6 in production cannot run, use any Rails db, or and rake db commands because a table is undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently our project runs in development, but when run with `RAILS_ENV=production` I am unable to run the project:

```
coolGuy@coolGuy-home:~/repos/raamble_on-project6-beta$ RAILS_ENV=production rails server
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.0.2.2 application starting in production 
=> Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
    91: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
    90: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
    89: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
    88: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
    87: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    86: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    85: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    84: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    83: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    82: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    81: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    80: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
    79: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    78: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    77: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    76: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `perform'
    75: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `tap'
    74: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
    73: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:39:in `start'
    72: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:311:in `start'
    71: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:379:in `handle_profiling'
    70: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:312:in `block in start'
    69: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
    68: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
    67: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    66: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
    65: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
    64: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
    63: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
    62: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    61: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:49:in `require_relative'
    60: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
    59: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
    58: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
    57: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
    56: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    55: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    54: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    53: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    52: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    51: from /home/ray/repos/raamble_on-project6-beta/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
    50: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in `initialize!'
    49: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    48: from /home/ray/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    47: from /home/ray/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    46: from /home/ray/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    45: from /home/ray/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    44: from /home/ray/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    43: from /home/ray/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    42: from /home/ray/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    41: from /home/ray/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    40: from /home/ray/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    39: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
    38: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
    37: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
    36: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:129:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    35: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
    34: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
    33: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
    32: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in `execute_hook'
    31: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:62:in `with_execution_control'
    30: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `block in execute_hook'
    29: from /home/ray/repos/raamble_on-project6-beta/config/application.rb:52:in `block in <class:Application>'
    28: from /home/ray/repos/raamble_on-project6-beta/config/application.rb:52:in `each'
    27: from /home/ray/repos/raamble_on-project6-beta/config/application.rb:113:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Application>'
    26: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:18:in `method_missing'
    25: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:60:in `valid?'
    24: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:60:in `all?'
    23: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:60:in `block in valid?'
    22: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:352:in `columns_hash'
    21: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:477:in `load_schema'
    20: from /home/ray/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:230:in `mon_synchronize'
    19: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:480:in `block in load_schema'
    18: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_decorators.rb:51:in `load_schema!'
    17: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/attributes.rb:247:in `load_schema!'
    16: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:490:in `load_schema!'
    15: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:82:in `columns_hash'
    14: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:76:in `columns'
    13: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:114:in `columns'
    12: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:817:in `column_definitions'
    11: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:63:in `query'
    10: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:708:in `log'
     9: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
     8: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:717:in `block in log'
     7: from /home/ray/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:230:in `mon_synchronize'
     6: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:718:in `block (2 levels) in log'
     5: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:64:in `block in query'
     4: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:47:in `permit_concurrent_loads'
     3: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:187:in `yield_shares'
     2: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:48:in `block in permit_concurrent_loads'
     1: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:65:in `block (2 levels) in query'
/home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:65:in `exec': ERROR:  relation "courses" does not exist (PG::UndefinedTable)
LINE 8:  WHERE a.attrelid = '"courses"'::regclass
                            ^
    91: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
    90: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
    89: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
    88: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
    87: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    86: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    85: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    84: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    83: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    82: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    81: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    80: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
    79: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    78: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    77: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    76: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `perform'
    75: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `tap'
    74: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
    73: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:39:in `start'
    72: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:311:in `start'
    71: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:379:in `handle_profiling'
    70: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:312:in `block in start'
    69: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
    68: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
    67: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    66: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
    65: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
    64: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
    63: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
    62: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    61: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:49:in `require_relative'
    60: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
    59: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
    58: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
    57: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
    56: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    55: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    54: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    53: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    52: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    51: from /home/ray/repos/raamble_on-project6-beta/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
    50: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in `initialize!'
    49: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    48: from /home/ray/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    47: from /home/ray/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    46: from /home/ray/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    45: from /home/ray/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    44: from /home/ray/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    43: from /home/ray/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    42: from /home/ray/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    41: from /home/ray/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    40: from /home/ray/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    39: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
    38: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
    37: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
    36: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:129:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    35: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
    34: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
    33: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
    32: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in `execute_hook'
    31: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:62:in `with_execution_control'
    30: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `block in execute_hook'
    29: from /home/ray/repos/raamble_on-project6-beta/config/application.rb:52:in `block in <class:Application>'
    28: from /home/ray/repos/raamble_on-project6-beta/config/application.rb:52:in `each'
    27: from /home/ray/repos/raamble_on-project6-beta/config/application.rb:113:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Application>'
    26: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:18:in `method_missing'
    25: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:60:in `valid?'
    24: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:60:in `all?'
    23: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:60:in `block in valid?'
    22: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:352:in `columns_hash'
    21: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:477:in `load_schema'
    20: from /home/ray/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:230:in `mon_synchronize'
    19: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:480:in `block in load_schema'
    18: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_decorators.rb:51:in `load_schema!'
    17: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/attributes.rb:247:in `load_schema!'
    16: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:490:in `load_schema!'
    15: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:82:in `columns_hash'
    14: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:76:in `columns'
    13: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:114:in `columns'
    12: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:817:in `column_definitions'
    11: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:63:in `query'
    10: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:708:in `log'
     9: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
     8: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:717:in `block in log'
     7: from /home/ray/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:230:in `mon_synchronize'
     6: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:718:in `block (2 levels) in log'
     5: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:64:in `block in query'
     4: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:47:in `permit_concurrent_loads'
     3: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:187:in `yield_shares'
     2: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:48:in `block in permit_concurrent_loads'
     1: from /home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:65:in `block (2 levels) in query'
/home/ray/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:65:in `exec': PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "courses" does not exist (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
LINE 8:  WHERE a.attrelid = '"courses"'::regclass
```

This error does not appear in development. There was an issue earlier with this table where a member of my team had deleted several migrations creating this table and a column for it, however, after some patching I was able to get it working in the development environment again.

I also tried using SQLite as the database instead of PostgreSQL but I still had no luck.

How do I fix production?

Comment: This is your issue: _There was an issue earlier with this table where a member of my team had deleted several migrations creating this table and a column for it._ You'll need to do the same patching in the production environment to get it happy again.

Comment: Yeah I figured. I'm to get it to run using RAILS_ENV=production locally on my machine first. I have no idea how to patch it in production without using rails db:migrate though

Comment: Issue with running ENV=production on your local machine is you are eager loading all the classes, so your patch didn't quite work.  There's still something missing.  Yes, migrations are the best tool to use (repeatable) and you can see if you can make a couple to get you fixed locally. But you might need to get direct database access and get your DDL skills out.

Comment: Hmm alright. One of the issues is is that the database I'm using is fresh too. I haven't gotten the code to even add tables to the database

Comment: Would it be easier to do a fresh clone into a new file and try it there?

Comment: So I just added the table into database that said was missing, but now it is giving a no method error for find_by_courseNumber which is a column in the database

Comment: that's not a very railsy looking column name or method name.  The column should be named `course_number` and the method should be `find_by_course_number` [which actually is deprecated in newer versions of rails and should be replaced by  `find_by(course_number: some_var)` ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `schema.rb` is a valid version of your database schema you can use it instead of migrations for your production.

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:schema:load
```

loads the schema that is already generated in db/schema.rb into the database.

You might need to create or drop/create your production db first. If I understand correctly there are no real data there yet.

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:drop
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create
```